# Button as both submission and calling a function

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, django

I have a Django query where in would take month as input and display pdf file with the query data.

```
element = request.GET.get('q')
    query=employeeModel.objects.filter(month__contains = element,username = request.user).values_list()
```

this is template of that query

```
<h1>Employee PaySlip Generation</h1>
<h5>Hello {{request.user}}</h5>
    <form method="GET" action="">
    <span><input type="text"  name='q' placeholder="Search: Month" value="{{ request.GET.get }}"/></span>
    <span><input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" value="Search" >
    </form>
```

I dont understand how to and what to do so, button would not only submit typed value to the query but also call pdf_generate function.

edit

utils.py

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template

from xhtml2pdf import pisa

def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None
```

from utils.py import reder_to_pdf

views.py

```
def user_pdf(request):
    template = get_template('payslip.html')

    element = request.GET.get('q')
    print(element)
    query = employeeModel.objects.values_list().filter(username= request.user,month__contains = element )[0]
    name = query[1]
    emp_id = query[2]
    context = {'query_name':name, 'query_id':emp_id}
    html = template.render(context)
    pdf = render_to_pdf('payslip.html', context)


    return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

Comment: So why can't you call `pdf_generate` at the end of the Python code you give above?

Comment: @DanielRoseman when i call `pdf generator` it says `ValueError at /home/employee/pdf
Cannot use None as a query value`

Comment: It not taking input value !

Comment: You need to show the exact code you are using, in context.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yeah, i have edited the question with views.py

Comment: I don't know why you're obscuring this. What is `do thing with queries`, and what is `{stufs with queries}`? Show the real code, along with the code of `render_to_pdf` and the full error traceback.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sorry, i didnt give complete code, now i have edited with complete   code.. please have a look..

Comment: The error traceback for the `ValueError` is still missing - so I am going to have to guess that `q` was not in `request.GET`, meaning that `request.GET.get('q')` defaulted to `None` which made the query fail when trying to do `month__contains=None`. If you have an error, always post the full traceback; an error without a traceback is like phone book with all numbers but no names.